# argparse: building a list of dict from CLI arguments?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

Designing a hierarchical CLI program. Something like:

```shell
$ python -m foo -'{' -c 'wow' -b 'has' -d 55 -'}' \
                -'{' -c 'haz' -b 'wow' -'}' \
                -'{' -d 56 -'}'
```

Which I would like to `return`:

```
[
    { 'c': 'wow', 'b': 'has', 'd': 55 },
    { 'c': 'haz', 'b': 'wow' },
    { 'd': 56 }
]
```

Primary question: how do I build this in [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), i.e., without a separate function that runs after `vars(parser.parse_args())`?

Auxilliary question: is building hierarchies like this in a CLI interface—i.e., not in an external json file or as `type=yaml.loads`—but as proper CLI property/values breaking some convention, that should make me reconsider this design?

PS: I can trivially create this without argparse using [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv), one extra `list` and a scope scalar. But `argparse` would give me auto-help, auto-complete, default values, type-safety and more… so would prefer to use it.

EDIT: `sys.argv[1:]` example:

```
[ '-m', 'foo', '-{', '-c', 'wow', '-b', 'has', '-d', '55', '-}',
  '-{', '-c', 'haz', '-b', 'wow', '-}', '-{', '-d', '56', '-}' ]
```

Comment: I don't quite follow your notation.  It might help if you listed some of the `sys.argv` lists that you are parsing.

Comment: A more common approach to passing structured arguments is like this: `-foo="c:wow;b:has:d:55" -bar="c:haz;b:wow"` etc. This is not to say you're breaking a convention, just that your approach is quite unique.and might be hard for users to grasp.

Comment: @hpaulj Added `sys.argv` example

Comment: @Błotosmętek Yeah I was worried about that, but also trying to be DRY and want to make it simple to store portion of your CLI in simple shell strings so they can be concatenated into your larger argument.

Comment: `argparse` treats all strings starting with a '-' as optionals flags. In your case that would include '-{', '-}', '-d' etc.  Also it tries to handle those in an order independent manner.  I can't imagine handling that list with `argparse`.

Comment: Yeah, all I could think of is https://stackoverflow.com/a/60442802 - but I'm sure there's a cleaner way…

Answer (score 1):

I think there is the loose 'convention' that CLI arguments should be reasonably simple; once you start putting serious amounts data on the command line, then maybe you should reconsider your design. After all, files are designed to hold data.

Answer (score 0):

Built a basic version, only handling one level of hierarchy:

### Program

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentTypeError
from sys import argv
from pprint import pprint


def build_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser(prog='python -m foo', description='.')
    parser.add_argument('-c')
    parser.add_argument('-b')
    parser.add_argument('-d', type=int)
    return parser


def main():
    level, working, whole = 0, [], []
    for arg in argv[1:]:
        if arg == '-{':
            level += 1
        elif arg == '-}':
            whole.append(tuple(working))
            working.clear()
            level -= 1
        else:
            working.append(arg)
    if level & 1 != 0:
        raise ArgumentTypeError('Imbalanced {}')
    parser = build_parser()

    return tuple(map(lambda args: parser.parse_args(args), whole))
    # For list of dicts, modify ^ vars(parser.parse_args(args))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pprint(main(), indent=4)
```

### I/O

```
$ python -m foo -'{' -c 'wow' -b 'has' -d 55 -'}' \
                -'{' -c 'haz' -b 'wow' -'}' \
                -'{' -d 56 -'}'
(   Namespace(b='has', c='wow', d=55),
    Namespace(b='wow', c='haz', d=None),
    Namespace(b=None, c=None, d=56))
```